# Next.js: Are there any ways to catch error when exporting SSG?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I need to catch all the errors when exporting with Next.js. Currently, I can only catch the errors when fetching data for the components, i.e try-catch in `getStaticProps`. But when it comes to rendering errors that are related to a component, I don't know if there are any ways to catch them.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.